# Is 'query' a keyword in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

```
> db.Log.findOne()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4f456b6413536c52836ed9d2"),
"action" : "POST",
"url" : "/path/to/resource",
"query" : "key1=value1,;key2=value2,;key3=value3",
"startDate" : ISODate("2012-02-22T22:25:39.517Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2012-02-22T22:25:40.450Z")
}
```

Here is the response I get from the query below:

```
> db.Log.find( { query: { $regex: /key1/, $options:'i' } } )

error: {
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $regex",
"code" : 17287
}
```

The same query works fine if it were some field other than 'query'(such as 'url'). Does the field name 'query' have a special interpretation for regex queries?

Comment: I haven't tested if this conflicts with what you have or not, but according to the docs "$query" is an operator. Here is the documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/query/#op._S_query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MongoDB is treating `query` the same as the [`$query`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/query/#op._S_query) operator.

It works if you place your query within a `$query` operator (or another `query` for that matter):

```
db.Log.find( {$query: { query: { $regex: /key1/, $options:'i' } } } )
```

It's not specific to your use of `$regex` as I could reproduce the problem with other queries as well.

Checked the MongoDB JIRA and it's a known issue: [SERVER-8025](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-8025).

Comment: Ah yes. That sounds like a known issue then. Thanks!